# Expression resolves to an unused function and use of unresolved identifier 'dispatch' errors

Tags: swift

I researched many topics on stackoverflow but couldn't find any solution for my problem. Firstly, I got two errors like these '' use of unresolved identifier 'dispatch' '' and '' expression resolves to an unused function''. And then I read a few topics and fixed first error. However, I am not sure about that. You can see these in the code below

```
    var imageURL: NSURL? {

                       didSet {
                           image = nil
                           if view.window != nil {
                               self.fetchImage
                           }
                       }
                   }

     private func fetchImage() {
               if let url = imageURL {
                   dispatch.async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)) {
                       let contentsOfURL = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL)
                       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                       if url == self.imageURL {
                           if let ImageData = contentsOfURL {
                               self.image = UIImage(data: ImageData as Data)
                               }

                           } else {
                               print ("ignored data returned from url \(url)")
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
```

After that the first problem was gone. However, the second error is still going on ('' expression resolves to an unused function''). the error is occured in the self.fetchimage code line

```
var imageURL: NSURL? {

               didSet {
                   image = nil
                   if view.window != nil {
                       self.fetchImage
                   }
               }
           }

           private func fetchImage() {
               if let url = imageURL {

                   DispatchQueue.global().async {
                       let contentsOfURL = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL)
                       DispatchQueue.main.async {

                       if url == self.imageURL {
                           if let ImageData = contentsOfURL {
                               self.image = UIImage(data: ImageData as Data)
                               }
                           } else {
                               print ("ignored data returned from url \(url)")
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you aren't calling the `fetchImage` function properly. Try this :

```
if view.window != nil {
   self.fetchImage()
}
```

Don't forget the `()` after the function name.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helpin. It works. What do you think about first solution is it correct ?

Comment: It has the same issue with the missing ()

Comment: So you said my first solution is not necessary ? But I tried only using () and didn't change the dispatch code line. second first error appears again. when ı changed it was fixed.

Comment: Not sure what the problem with the first example is, but you used "old style - pre Swift 3" GCD code. Maybe that's the issue.

Comment: I see Bogdan thanks a lot again. it was very descriptive